# libgdx reset OrthographicCamera position

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d-games

i have a problem with resetting the position of the camera in a Java application.
It's a side scroller game, where the camera is focused (zoomed) on a part of the screen..

in one class (UI) the camera has the following settings:

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, FlappyWizardGame.WIDTH / 2,FlappyWizardGame.HEIGHT / 2);
```

in the update() method the camera should follow the moving figure:

```
camera.position.x = wizard.getPosition().x + 80;
```

in the render() method:

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

now my problem is, when the player loses, another UI should pop up. But because of the camera's zoom, the Background (Texture) is not shown correctly..

I hope you understand what i mean and thanks for the help!

Kind regards!

**EDIT:**
It appears that the problem is with the SpriteBatch, because it's set to "Camera.combined". Is there any way to reset it?

Comment: Don't use the same camera for the gameplay and the UI.

Comment: Both UI's extend an abstract class where the camera is implemented
Do you meant to implement the camera separately in each class?

Comment: `sb.setProjectionMatrix(gameCamera.combined); sb.begin(); //draw stuff sb.setProjectionMatrix(uiCamera.combined); //draw stuff sb.end();`

Answer (score 0):

Offset the background Texture to draw at wizard.getPosition().x - offset. Where offset is the distance from the origin(top left) of wizard to the left side of the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure i understood what you mean exactly.. 
Would you be so kind and explain your idea to me please?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to reposition the camera like this:

```
camera.setToOrtho(false, FlappyWizardGame.WIDTH, FlappyWizardGame.HEIGHT);
```

and in the render method to reset the SpriteBatch like this:

```
sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Thanks for your help!